# creating responsive grid sytem and ordering

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple section which I am creating for my app, this section contains one row with 3 columns each column have 3 divs.

JSFIDDLE: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6v9khebL/10/)

Here is what it should look in desktop view

[image]

Here is how it should look in small device

[image]

so far here is my solution I tried, but am not getting what I want .

HTML

```
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-top-details_second">

                    </div>

                </div>
             <div class="row subrow_bottom">
                  <div class="col-md-4 left-bottom">

                </div>
                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 middle">
                <div class="row subrow">
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-top-details_first">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-top-details_second">

                    </div>

                </div>
             <div class="row subrow_bottom">
                  <div class="col-md-4 left-bottom">

                </div>
                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 right">
                  <div class="row subrow">
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-top-details_first">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-top-details_second">

                    </div>

                </div>
             <div class="row subrow_bottom">
                <div class="col-md-4 left-bottom">

                </div>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background: red;

}
#for-her{
height: 1200px;
background: red;
overflow: hidden;
}
.col-md-4 {    
  height: 200px;
    margin: 20px 0px;

}

.left-top-details_first{
    border: 2px solid white;
     height: 200px;
         width: 100%;
}
.left-top-details_second{
border: 2px solid white;
     height: 200px;
         width: 100%;
}

.left-bottom{
    border: 2px solid white;
     height: 200px;
     width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
    .main-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }

}
```

website max-width should be 1240px;

What do I need to change to get what I want? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: please cheange the "bootstrap-4" tag to "twitter-bootstrap" in order to avoid inconveniences. Bootstrap 4 has crucial changes according to the solution and it won't work with your linked Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: am using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear the you have 3 columns and inside each column you have 2 others. So your code can simply be something like below:

```css
.col{
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 80px;
  margin:5px;
}

.col-12 > div {
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  margin:5px;
}

body {
  background: pink!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't the cols inside the col-md-4 => row be col-6?

in this case, in bootstrap 3 every col-6 or col-12 should be col-xs-6 and col-xs-12

Comment: @PatrikAlexits with bootstrap using col will make it fill automatically the needed space, so col will make it easy to add extra margin without overflow

Comment: @PatrikAlexits you can read about here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif thanks for the help, now when I want to add space between `col-12-p-0 ` columns it looks like this `http://jsfiddle.net/c3th8v29/5/` what do I need to do to get space between those columns the same as other columns?

Comment: @user9964622 I have updated my code, better use another element inside and you can easily do this

Comment: @TemaniAfif  am not so good in bootstrap 4 , what would you suggest the tablet view?   thanks

Comment: @user9964622 I think like the mobile view should be good. Since we have 3 columns, better keep them one on tablet and mobile

Comment: but your solution I have all boxes in one row in a tablets view, do I need to add col-sm-12 ? to get the same as mobile? or something else?

Comment: @user9964622 yes true, simply change the `md` I have use with `lg`. This is the only classe you need to adjust (either  `sm`, `md`, `lg`, etc https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to manually edit the default CSS of your Bootstrap 4 classes.

You just have to nest all your boxes inside a row and then add the class names `col-lg-2 col-12` to each box to get the layout that you want.

*`col-lg-2 col-12` will allot each box with **2 columns / 12 columns** (6 per row) in large screens and **12 columns / 12 columns** (1 per row) in tablets and phones.*

Inside each box, add another row and assign the class name `col-6` to both your two inner boxes and nest your bottom box inside a full-width box.

`col-6` will allot each of the two inner boxes with **6 columns / 12 columns** (2 per row) in all screen sizes.

---

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/1wm8d2x4/32/) or run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```css
body{width: 100%;height: 100%; text-align: center;}
#for-her{
height: 1200px;
width: 100%;
background: red;
overflow: hidden;
}
.col-lg-2 {border: 2px solid white;margin: 10px 0px;}
.col-lg-12 {background-color: #FFF; color: #000;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="for-her">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-6">ABCD</div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">Yes</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col{
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 80px;
  margin:5px;
}

.col-12 > div {
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  margin:5px;
}

body {
  background: #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0">
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```